# OutOfMemory Error in Custom ListView Adapter [Mono Android]

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, android-listview, out-of-memory

Hello Stack Overflow Android Users,

Please help with the following question:

### Problem

I'm writing an a feature for an app that lists species of fish. I'm using a custom ListView Adapter class (let's call this FishSpeciesListAdapter) for the adapter. I have 27 fish species recorded as a default for the program as for now (you will eventually be able to add some yourself as well). The problem is that when I link the adapter to the actual listview xml object and scroll down the list, after a while, I get the following error:

```
UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError' was thrown.
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <0x00080>
at Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (byte[],int,int) <0x001db>
at FishinTales.FishSpeciesListAdapter.GetView (int,Android.Views.View,Android.Views.ViewGroup) <0x002f7>
at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.n_GetView_ILandroid_view_View_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_ (intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr) <0x00093>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.5dcc133f-a229-41c4-80e2-f5f5260ecdad (intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr) <0x0004b>

  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:392)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:405)
    at fishintales.FishSpeciesListAdapter.n_getView(Native Method)
    at fishintales.FishSpeciesListAdapter.getView(FishSpeciesListAdapter.java:55)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1294)
    at android.widget.ListView.addViewBelow(ListView.java:2896)
    at android.widget.ListView.scrollListItemsBy(ListView.java:2825)
    at android.widget.ListView.arrowScrollImpl(ListView.java:2322)
    at android.widget.ListView.arrowScroll(ListView.java:2269)
    at android.widget.ListView.commonKey(ListView.java:2071)
    at android.widget.ListView.onKeyDown(ListView.java:2018)
    at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1037)
    at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3740)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:786)
    at android.widget.ListView.dispatchKeyEvent(ListView.java:2003)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
    at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Unhandled Exception:
Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError' was thrown.
at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallStaticObjectMethod (intptr,intptr,Android.Runtime.JValue[]) <0x00080>
at Android.Graphics.BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray (byte[],int,int) <0x001db>
at FishinTales.FishSpeciesListAdapter.GetView (int,Android.Views.View,Android.Views.ViewGroup) <0x002f7>
at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.n_GetView_ILandroid_view_View_Landroid_view_ViewGroup_ (intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr) <0x00093>
at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.5dcc133f-a229-41c4-80e2-f5f5260ecdad (intptr,intptr,int,intptr,intptr) <0x0004b>

  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:392)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:405)
    at fishintales.FishSpeciesListAdapter.n_getView(Native Met
```

Here's my Custom ListAdapter:

```
public class FishSpeciesListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    Context n_context;
    List<AppCode.Specie> n_specieData;

    public FishSpeciesListAdapter (Context context, List<AppCode.Specie> specieData)
    {
        this.n_context = context;
        this.n_specieData = specieData;
    }

    public override int Count {
        get { return this.n_specieData.Count; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem (int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v;
        if(convertView==null){

            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.FromContext(parent.Context);
            v = li.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Adapter_FishSpeciesIcon, null);
        }
        else
        {
            v = convertView;
        }
        ImageView iconImage = (ImageView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.xml_adapter_fishSpeciesIconImage);
        TextView nameText = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.xml_adapter_fishSpeciesNameText);
        TextView scientificNameText = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.xml_adapter_fishSpeciesScientificNameText);

        nameText.Text = this.n_specieData[position].Name;
        scientificNameText.Text = this.n_specieData[position].ScientificName;

        if (this.n_specieData[position].RelatedMedia.AttachedPhotos.Count < 1)
        {
            iconImage.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon); 
        }
        else
        {
            iconImage.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(this.n_specieData[position].RelatedMedia.AttachedPhotos[0], 0, this.n_specieData[position].RelatedMedia.AttachedPhotos[0].Length));  
        }   

        return v;
    }
}
```

### Other Research On My Behalf

All images are in the range of 100-300KB. 
Will this really cause this problem?

Please [reference my last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13684806/custom-listview-adapter-showing-incorrect-values-mono-android) for additional code as it is kind of related but needs a new question. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: how big (in pixels) are your images ?

Comment: The images range in pixel size anywhere from '347px x 222px' to '769px x 325px'

Comment: you probably want to resize them when you load them

Comment: I noticed that it does take some time for all of the images to load into my main 'MyApp' class. It succeeds in loading all into byte arrays and loads the listview screen correctly, when I scroll down to the largest size image (301KB), I get the error and can never see the image in the listview. They are all PNG files as I need this type for transparent backgrounds in the images themselves. I will try to make the largest file first so in theory, when I run it next time, it should fail right when the screen loads and I won't even be able to see anything.

Comment: Just tried it and it still gives the error when I scroll halfway down the page. Is the adapter always referencing/decoding the files when they show up on the screen? In this case you would be correct, however, I changed it around and added the largest images first so technically wouldn't you assume that the screen won't even load and give the error on startup?

Comment: I'll attempt to resize them but does anyone know if there is a total size limit for a given listview adapter? I'm still not sure if it is failing on a single image or if by scrolling down it has to reference all the images that it has come in contact with???

Comment: also, you may consider loading all images at once to make sure there is enough room and your images don't get loaded more than once.

Comment: I do make sure that they are loaded at one time and never again, I have a Debug Log that confirms this for me. And that part executes successfully. Still resizing the images to see if that works. Which if it does, how can I assure myself that adding more later (although resized) will still execute properly?

Comment: Doesn't work. I reduced the images to half their sizes. They werent that big to begin with so I know this isn't the problem. It keeps saying "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget" after scrolling down the page about 3/4 of the way. It's so wierd???

Comment: i would consider loading images in an array somewhere once and for all

Comment: That was it! I created an array of bitmaps at the creation of the adapter. Much like the following link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081497/listview-shows-wrong-images) Now I can scroll through all of them. I guess what it was doing was getting held up on decoding byte arrays into Bitmaps everytime GetView was being called. So what I did was convert them all in the constructor and made a cache of Bitmaps to reference in the GetView method. Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you use a cache, i recommend the use of WeakReferences to avoid outofmemory issues in case you really have lots of images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it!

What it was doing was getting held up on decoding byte arrays into Bitmaps everytime GetView was being called. So what I did was convert them all in the constructor and made a cache of Bitmaps to reference when the GetView method was called.

Here is my updated Custom ListView Adapter that works.

```
public class FishSpeciesListAdapter : BaseAdapter
{
    Context n_context;
    List<AppCode.Specie> n_specieData;
    List<Bitmap> n_bitmapCache;

    public FishSpeciesListAdapter (Context context, List<AppCode.Specie> specieData)
    {
        this.n_context = context;
        this.n_specieData = specieData;
        this.n_bitmapCache = new List<Bitmap>();
        this.LoadBitmapsIntoCache();
    }

    private void LoadBitmapsIntoCache()
    {
        foreach(AppCode.Specie specie in this.n_specieData)
        {
            if (specie.RelatedMedia.AttachedPhotos.Count < 1)
            {
                this.n_bitmapCache.Add(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(this.n_context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon)); 
            }
            else
            {
                this.n_bitmapCache.Add(BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(specie.RelatedMedia.AttachedPhotos[0], 0, specie.RelatedMedia.AttachedPhotos[0].Length));  
            }
        }
    }

    public override int Count {
        get { return this.n_specieData.Count; }
    }

    public override Java.Lang.Object GetItem (int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(convertView==null){

            LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.FromContext(parent.Context);
            convertView = li.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Adapter_FishSpeciesIcon, null);
        }

        ImageView iconImage = (ImageView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.xml_adapter_fishSpeciesIconImage);
        TextView nameText = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.xml_adapter_fishSpeciesNameText);
        TextView scientificNameText = (TextView)convertView.FindViewById(Resource.Id.xml_adapter_fishSpeciesScientificNameText);

        nameText.Text = this.n_specieData[position].Name;
        scientificNameText.Text = this.n_specieData[position].ScientificName;
        iconImage.SetImageBitmap(this.n_bitmapCache[position]); 

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

After calling LoadBitmapsIntoCache() in the constructor and saving the Bitmaps to a list. The problem was resolved and I could scroll through all the fish species without any OutOfMemory Errors. Thanks to all who helped.